# How to display an object of objects in angular?

Tags: angular

So, there is an object, inside which there are some other objects, and inside them there are more objects. Please, tell me how to output key values. I suppose *ngFor won't help

```
const data = {
    first_data: {
      id: "1",
      name: "First",
      type: "Administration",
      sections: {
        main_section: {
            id: "main_section",
            name: "Main Section",
            sub_sections: {
                sub_first: {
                    id: "12",
                    name:  "Subsection_name",
                    questions: {
                      first_question: {
                        id: "44",
                        name: "Answer"
                      },
                      second_question: {
                        id: "33",
                        name: "True"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Quite a horrible format :-). You could use a keyvalue pipe in an ngFor I guess?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ngFor`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) combined with [`KeyValuePipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe):

> Transforms Object or Map into an array of key value pairs.
>
> ```
> <div *ngFor="let item of object | keyvalue">
>   {{item.key}}:{{item.value}}
> </div>
> ```

However, I guess you need some kind of [custom pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) to transform your data. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43773676/how-to-do-ngfor-loop-on-nested-json-object) including [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43775141/2436655) - maybe worth a try.